# Parsing a HTML page with python

Tags: python, html-parsing

I would like to do parsing in a website source code like this

```
If (something="<BODY>"):
 while (something!="</BODY>"):
  if (something="https")   :
    put the word on a list
```

**The thing is I don't know a way to parse**(I mean the function with which I read the source code). 
I have the source code in an object i.e `MyObj`

Which is the best way to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an HTML parsing library to parse the HTML. Two popular, good ones are [beautifulsoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) and [lxml](http://lxml.de/).

Comment: Is there a way to parse a HTML file without using these 2 libraries ? With regex?

Comment: @georgemano: Regex is not the right tool to *parse* HTML.

Comment: @Is there any way to parse other than using external libraries like `beautifulsoup` and `lxml`?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Here's an infamous answer as to why you should not try to roll your own parser / regexs for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: See http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#kinds-of-objects or http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all

Comment: `xml.dom.minidom` is included in Python

Answer (score 2):

[Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is the best HTML parsing library I've used, take a look at it.

Comment: Is there a way to parse a HTML file without using this library ? With regex or something?